# how can I find the number of sessions in jvm?

Tags: java, session, jvm, application-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find number of active sessions created from a given client IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679465/find-number-of-active-sessions-created-from-a-given-client-ip)
>   [Getting a list of active sessions in Tomcat using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069444/getting-a-list-of-active-sessions-in-tomcat-using-java)

I want to know the number of sessions in JVM. How can I find it to manage it in application server? Application server is tomcat.

Comment: That information is not contained in the JVM. See the Tomcat manual.

Comment: You can use `HttpSessionListener` Check [Find number of active sessions created from a given client IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679465/find-number-of-active-sessions-created-from-a-given-client-ip)