# Number of Active Sessions in Tomcat

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans, yaxis, tomcat8.5

I have my web services jar file deployed under `webapps\nyx\WEB-INF\services` in my tomcat server. Now I am trying to get no of active sessions using below code inside a web service method.

```
MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Manager,context=/nyx/services,host=localhost");
Object activeSessions =mBeanServer.getAttribute(objectName,"activeSessions");
```

But this gives me **Instance not found** exception.
Can someone help me with the value for the context attribute?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069444/getting-a-list-of-active-sessions-in-tomcat-using-java

Comment: I checked that. But the problem here is what is the context I should use when the web services are deployed under webapps\nyx\WEB-INF\services directory

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069444/getting-a-list-of-active-sessions-in-tomcat-using-java), reading your code the first thing that i think is try using JMX (Java Management eXtension)

Something like this:

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi");
try(JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url)) {
  MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
  ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Manager,context=/,host=localhost");
  Object value = mbsc.getAttribute(mbeanName, "activeSessions");
}
```

**EDIT**

If you need to retrieve the number of session ***locally*** your code should be fine, try with your code but getting the context at runtime.
Override the init method:

```
@Override
public void init(final ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    context = config.getServletContext().getContextPath();
}
```

Then pass it as ObjectName parameter:

```
ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Manager,context="+context+",host=localhost");
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response.  I  tried this but this gives me                                       
"java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is " exception. What should be the ip and the port I should use if my server  ip is y31 and port number 3389.

Comment: in order to execute in a right way jmx you must pass some addiotional params...  
Maybe the exception can be thrown because you are omitting
`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false`
or some other parameter

Comment: Ohh, thank you. I ll check that. Bdw in config.getServletContext() I couldnt find the method getContextPath();

Comment: Refer tho this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837285/different-ways-to-get-servlet-context in order to get the ServletContext depending on your needs

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But still I couldnt come up with a solution.

Comment: Here I am deploying my web services in a subdirectory under  WEB-INF. Will that be the problem

Comment: Maybe... Can you try changing your deploy path?